# Shortest route between large amount of points

Tags: qgis, routing

I have to check the street lights of various communities. There are approx. 540 lamps to check, I was wondering if QGIS (or any other opensource software like PostGIS or R) can help me finding the best (aka shortest) way. I have the lights-to-check in a shapefile. 
I guess it is too complex to calculate with my PC but thought it might be worth a shot to ask here for any creative solutions!

Comment: It seems to be a version of the Traveling Saleman Problem and a GRASS tool exists : [v.net.salesman](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/v.net.salesman.html)

Comment: yeah, classical Travelin Salesman Problem. the thing with the GRASS tool is, i have only OSM as network. I will try and extract a network from there and see then where v.net.salesman brings me to

Comment: you can also use other GRASS `v.net` tools for clean and connect network.